# Exception :Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4: using Hcatalog with Hive-0.14.0

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have following tools :
    **Hadoop-2.6.0, 
    Hive-0.14.0, 
    hbase-0.94.8, 
    sqoop-1.4.5, 
    pig-0.14.0** installed in a psuedo distributed environment on **Ubuntu 14.0.4.**

My goal is to use Hcatalog as an interface to work with Hive, Pig, MapReduce applications.

**Steps I did:**
1. I have Mysql configured as remote metastore, with mysql-connector-java-5.1.37 jar copied in HIVE_HOME/lib. I have created hive-site.xml in HIVE_HOME/conf for remote metastore but running on same machine.
2. I have hive-env.sh file with HADOOP_HOME pointing to Hadoop-2.6.0 home.
3. I have remote metastore running at port 9083
4. in bashrc file I have following env variables set:

```
#Hadoop variables start
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
#Hadoop variables end

export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
export PIG_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true

#PIG ENV VARIABLE
export PIG_HOME=/home/user/pig-0.14.0
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin

#Hive Env Variable
export HIVE_HOME=/home/user/hive-0.14.0/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

#HCatalog env 
export HCAT_HOME=$HIVE_HOME/hcatalog
export HCAT_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$HCAT_HOME/bin

HCATJAR=$HCAT_HOME/share/hacatalog/hive-hcatalog-core-0.14.0.jar
export HCATJAR

HCATPIGJAR=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter-0.14.0.jar
export HCATPIGJAR

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HCATJAR:$HCATPIGJAR:$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec-0.14.0.jar\
:$HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-metastore-0.14.0.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/jdo-api-*.jar:$HIVE_HOME/lib/libfb303-*.jar\
:$HIVE_HOME/lib/libthrift-*.jar:$HIVE_HOME/conf:$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

#Pig hcatalog integration
export PIG_OPTS=-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9083
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/*:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*:$HCATPIGJAR:$HIVE_HOME/conf:$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

**I am trying to invoke "hcat" command on HIVE_HOME/hcatalog/bin path. Below are the errors which is being generated:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:444)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.cli.HCatCli.main(HCatCli.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
**Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4**
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:427)
    ... 6 more
```

**Observation:** After Googling a lot, If I understand right "Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4" is hadoop version mismatch. 
So I added HADOOP_HOME in hive-env.sh to refer to hadoop-2.6.0. 
Error still persists. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help on this will be really appreciated.

Comment: have you found the solution @Chaya